# Making TAB key work in my win32 app

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I want to make the tab button work on my app , so when I press tab, it will change from one edit box to another, these are the edit box codes:

```
    case WM_CREATE:

    TextBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                            "",
                            WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_EX_LAYERED|WS_TABSTOP|WS_GROUP,
                            60,50,200,20,
                            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    DataBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                            "",
                            WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|WS_GROUP,
                            60,72,200,20,
                            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    MotivBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                            "",
                            WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|WS_GROUP,
                            60,92,200,20,
                            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
    PretBox = CreateWindow("EDIT",
                            "",
                            WS_BORDER|WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|WS_TABSTOP|WS_GROUP,
                            60,112,200,20,
                            hwnd,NULL,NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: What's the question ?

Comment: Using the TAB key to move to the next ctontrol is standard behaviour in Windows and other GUis anyway. So what exactly do you have a problem with?

Comment: Well, when I press the TAB key, nothing happens, it doesn't change focus from one edit box to another

Comment: If it helps, I can post the entire code..

Comment: Why are you including `WS_EX_LAYERED` as one of the window styles?

Comment: By mistake , meant to do that to a static text.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The fix is quite simple. Given the fact you're handling the WM_CREATE message, rather than the WM_INITDIALOG message, it seems safe to assume that you're adding the controls to a 'standard' window, rather than a 'dialog'.

With that in mind, I expect you've got something like the following in your winmain:

```
/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    TranslateMessage(&messages);
    /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
    DispatchMessage(&messages);
}
```

However, the documentation for `IsDialogMessage` states:

> "Although the IsDialogMessage function is intended for modeless dialog boxes, you can use it with any window that contains controls, enabling the windows to provide the same keyboard selection as is used in a dialog box. 
>   When IsDialogMessage processes a message, it checks for keyboard messages and converts them into selection commands for the corresponding dialog box. For example, the TAB key, when pressed, selects the next control or group of controls, and the DOWN ARROW key, when pressed, selects the next control in a group.
>
> Because the IsDialogMessage function performs all necessary translating and dispatching of messages, a message processed by IsDialogMessage must not be passed to the TranslateMessage or DispatchMessage function."

So, you can change your message pump to resemble the following:

```
/* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
    if (IsDialogMessage(hwnd, &messages) == 0)
    {
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }
}
```

Comment: I can add the main.cpp if it helps you figure out why it doesn't work, because I am getting nowhere with this..

Comment: You're welcome. Well in that case - I suggest you provide an SSCCE - Short Self Contained Compilable (Correct) Example (http://www.sscce.org/). That way, we'll be able to direct you to the oversight you've made, rather than just guessing. On a working project, removing the call to `IsDialogMessage` breaks the TAB key functionality, so there must be something else amiss too. :) **EDIT:** Just saw you suggestion of the `main.cpp` - sounds like we had the same idea at the same time!

Comment: Solved it ! Thank you,  there was some extra code (from my previous attempt in getting the TAB key to work) that I forgot to delete, now TAB key works great

Comment: Great! You're welcome. Pleased to hear you've fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I remember, you should use `WS_GROUP` only on the first entry. All following childwindows will be added to this group. When you create a new group, you use `WS_GROUP` again on the first window being created.
So keep the `WS_GROUP` on `TextBox` and remove it form the other windows.

You can read about this here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czada357.aspx#fbid=QnO2VZ2lQQD).

You also should use the `IsDialogMessage` in your message loop. You can see an [example here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/10/21/55384.aspx).

Comment: See my answer with an additional comment.

Comment: Yup, IsDialogMessage is the key to this one, I think.

Comment: Example link is the best of all the answers here!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and found adding the IsDialogMessage statement before TramnslateMessage and DispatchMessage (as shown in the accepted answer) fixed my problem.